# Java Testing for Maps

Tags: java

I've created a `List<Map<String, String>>` for a source file.  I've succeeded in creating a Map with the header values as keys and the information below them as values.  I've tested and verified everything in that method works.

In my next method I've implemented an iterator that will grab the next mapping for processing in a different class.  I'm trying to test to make sure that it's doing what I think it's doing and to verify what I want it to do.

Here's the code of the method:

```
  public Map contact(List<Map<String, String>> list) {
return list.iterator().next(); 
}
```

And here's my test code in the testing class:

```
  @Test
public void contact() throws Exception {

List<Map<String, String>> list = this.main.sourceToMap(source1.readLine());
Map nextContact = this.main.contact(list);

System.out.println(list.get(0));

Assert.assertEquals(nextContact,
    "zip=70116, address=6649 N Blue Gum St, city=New Orleans, " +
        "web=http://www.bentonjohnbjr.com, company_name=\"Benton, John B Jr\", " +
        "county=Orleans, phone2=504-845-1427, last_name=Butt, state=LA, first_name=James, " +
        "email=jbutt@gmail.com, phone1=504-621-8927");
}
```

Finally, here's the error i'm getting:

`java.lang.AssertionError: Expected :{zip=70116, address=6649 N Blue Gum St,city=New Orleans, web=http://www.bentonjohnbjr.com, company_name="Benton, John B Jr", county=Orleans, phone2=504-845-1427, last_name=Butt, state=LA, first_name=James, email=jbutt@gmail.com, phone1=504-621-8927}`

`Actual :zip=70116, address=6649 N Blue Gum St, city=New Orleans, web=http://www.bentonjohnbjr.com, company_name="Benton, John B Jr", county=Orleans, phone2=504-845-1427, last_name=Butt, state=LA, first_name=James, email=jbutt@gmail.com, phone1=504-621-8927`

The expected and actual are exactly the same with one one difference.  A "{ }" is in front and behind the string.

I think it's because it's expecting a Map instead of a String but I can't figure out what to type in to make it a Map instead of a string.

This is an assignment but not THE assignment.  This is just one small test that i'm trying to prove before moving on.

Thanks!  :D

Comment: I really would not recommend testing an object like this. You should be testing each of the fields. That way if you have some logic specifically around accessing a member, it's covered by this.

Comment: I agree; this is testing a method within the class.  Above this test code is all the test code i've already created testing each of the fields and other methods.

I wasn't trying to pollute the question with extra code that didn't matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You assertion is comparing a `Map` with a `String`. This fails of course, because the two aren't even the same type. In the error message you see a textual representation of your `nextContact` object. This seems to be created by invoking the `toString()` method of `Map`, which produces the result with the `{}` around the content.

To fix this you should compare the actual values in the map, e.g.

```
Assert.assertEquals(nextContact.get("zip"), "70116");
```

Comment: Yes.  That did it.  I didn't even realize it as I was thinking that I had written something that I wasn't supposed to.  I knew it had to be that the actual was a string when the method is supposed to return a map...I just couldn't think of it.

Plus this makes testing easier as I don't have to write the entire string.  

Thank you Adre!

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to compare in that way (whole map contents against the String) - consider two things:

1. First argument in `Assert.assertEquals(..)` method is expected value. So, swap your arguments to match the contract
2. Add curly braces to the expected value:  `Assert.assertEquals(
   "{zip=70116, address=6649 N Blue Gum St, city=New Orleans, " +
       "web=http://www.bentonjohnbjr.com, company_name=\"Benton, John B Jr\", " +
       "county=Orleans, phone2=504-845-1427, last_name=Butt, state=LA, first_name=James, " +
       "email=jbutt@gmail.com, phone1=504-621-8927}", nextContact.toString());`

   3. Add `toString()` method call to the map object so that both objects would have the same type

Comment: No this wouldn't work. You are still comparing a `String` with a `Map`. The representation with the curly braces is only used for the error message, not for the actual comparison.

Comment: Actually, you're right - my initial version of the test will fail. But if we add .toString() to map object - test passes. I'm a little bit confused with that. I though .toString() method would be automatically called